# what the reason behind <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_ERROR</GATE-M> android logs

Tags: android, android-webview, android-logcat

My application is using web view and every thing is working fine(no force close,no visible error) but in log cat i am getting unlimited and continuous logs like.

```
09-06 09:05:27.464: I/GATE(3471): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_ERROR</GATE-M>
```

my web view renders a local html file which resides in asset folder.From Android native code i am sending some string to webview to call a java script function.
because of unlimited logs i am not able to see my custom log message.

Can any please tell me the reason so can eliminate if i did any thing wrong.

Comment: I'm curious about it, too. I've just wanted to create a similar question. I think it comes from ADB. I usually have `GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>`. The Only thing I really know is that you can provocate this message while loading a URL wich is not reachable.

Answer (score -1):

I am loading the WebView using the Url from server. In my case it is not html file. Just check the input stream from the server. if any content is there then set webview otherwise dont.